# Spring Boot is missing bean used in child package

Tags: spring-boot, ehcache

Why my project report error: "***Consider defining a bean of type 'javax.cache.CacheManager' in your configuration.***"

**parent** build.gradle like:

```
dependencies {
  implementation "com.service2.child"
}
```

**parent** package is using bean from child package in below service:

```
package com.service1.parent;
import com.service2.child;

@Component
@ComponentScan("com.service2.child")  
public class ParentImpl {
  private final  Child child
  
  public ParentImpl(Child child) {
    this.child = child;
  }
}
```

the gradle in **child** package:

```
dependencies {
  api 'org.springframework.retry:spring-retry:1.3.3'
  api "javax.cache:cache-api:1.1.1"
  api "org.ehcache:ehcache:3.9.9"  // here has the implementation of 'javax.cache.CacheManager'
  ...
}
```

the service in **child** package is a cacheable service:

```
package com.service2.child;

import ...

@Configuration
@EnableRetry
@EnableScheduling
public class Child {

  @Cacheable(value = "token")
  @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 25*60, TimeUnit = TimeUnit.SECONDS)
  @Retryable(value = ServiceUnavailableException.class)
  public String getToken () {
    ...
  }
}
```

this is the cache config class in **child** package:

```
package com.service2.child;

import javax.cache.CacheManager;
import ...

@Configuration
@EnableCaching
public class ChildCacheConfig {
  private final CacheManager cacheManager;
  public ChildCacheConfig(CacheManager cacheManager) {
    this.cacheManager = cacheManager;
  }
}
```

I am new to Spring Boot but the error is confusion, since the "javax.cache.CacheManager" bean is used only in child package but I get this error on parent project gradle bootRun, why I have to implement it in parent package again; how to avoid have this kind of error?

Comment: If the bean is defined in the children, you don't need to redefine it in the parent but it would seem that there is something misconfigured. When importing a Spring Boot project into another, I usually add an `@Import` pointing to the main class of the "child" in the parent main class (or other `@Configuration` class)

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution, to add spring-boot-starter-cache to the parent project:

dependencies {
implementation group: "org.springframework.boot", name: "spring-boot-starter-cache"
}